# Pandas update column value if df1 index in df2 index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas, point-in-polygon

I have a dataframe of coordinates in which I perform point-in-polygon and it returns the set of points in the polygon.

df1 - Original coordinates

```
0              POINT (-97.96192929999999 29.8929939)
1              POINT (-97.98886109999999 29.8230438)
2              POINT (-97.6573715 30.15241810000001)
3              POINT (-97.68809509999998 30.3590794)
4              POINT (-97.37609860000001 31.0930271)
5              POINT (-97.66625980000001 30.3466492)
6                     POINT (-97.6666412 30.3455753)
...
```

df2 - Results

```
4       POINT (-97.37609860000001 31.0930271)
1496    POINT (-97.64907839999999 30.3872128)
445     POINT (-97.64907839999999 30.3872128)
2822    POINT (-97.649353 30.387228)
1369    POINT (-97.6488342 30.3873215)
6       POINT (-97.6666412 30.3455753)
2303    POINT (-97.6492767 30.38755039999999)
...
```

How would I add an "area" column in df1 and set the values = "area1" for the row indexes that are in both dfs? In the example above, rows 4 and 6 are in the results so I'd like to have an area column = "area1" for those rows in df1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the index, cause the pandas is index/column sensitive, which mean it will assign the new value base on the index matched.

So what you can do

```
df1['area']=df2['Value']
#df2['New']='are1' then df1['area']=df2['New']
```

Toy data

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'d1':[1,2,3]},index=[1,2,3])
df2=pd.DataFrame({'d2':[1,2,3]},index=[2,6,1])
df1['New']=df2.d2
df1
Out[724]: 
   d1  New
1   1  3.0
2   2  1.0
3   3  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, but instead of setting the new column value = df2's value, I just want to set all the new column values = to a static string like "area1"

Comment: @Calculus `df2['New']='are1'` then `df1['area']=df2['New']`